# How to change windows 10 search results order

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search, cortana

Is there a way I can change the order of my windows 10 start menu search results?
I want for example, when I press "V" to have the first result as "Viber", instead of "Visual Studio".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the search these past 5 days and selecting the app I want from the search results, it now actually appears as "Best match". So the Best match changes depending on what you mostly select when you search a certain keyword.

**Note:** I turned the "My device history" to "On", under the search settings.